# Resample Curve Node , length precision

Tags: geometry-nodes

can i get precision on resampling a curve in GN?
[image: help]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get precise values when you use *Length* mode if the whole curve's length isn't a multiple of the resampling length.

To quote the *Blender Manual* on the *Resample Curve* node found here: [Resample Curve Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/curve/resample_curve.html):

---

#### Inputs

###### Length

The approximate length between the control points of the new splines.

*and*

#### Modes

###### Length

Calculate the number of samples by splitting each spline into segments with the specified length. The length will be rounded down so that a whole number of samples will fit in each input spline.

---

As I can see in your screenshot it looks like your curve is 70 m long. Your resampling length is 11 m. This means, you'll have a segment number of

$$\frac{70m}{11m} \approx 6.36 $$

but since you can only separate the curve in an integral number of segments consisting of an integral number of points you'll get a rounded down 6 segments between 7 points.

Now Blender tries to evenly distribute the points between the start and endpoint of the curve, leaving you with a resampling length of

$$\frac{70m}{6} = 11.\bar{6}m $$

which is what you see there. Since 11 is no integral divisor of 70, you cannot get a precise 11m resampling of a 70m curve.

Of course, the smaller the resampling length, the smaller (and less noticeable) the error. If you would set the length to 1.1 instead of 11 for example, you'll get 63 segments with a length of 1.111...m which is closer to the desired value.

Comment: +1, very comprehensive!  I suppose you could suggest trimming the curve , to achieve exact intervals?

Comment: @RobinBetts Sure, but since the question is not giving any information in how far the original curve length is determined and has to stay unaltered for example, I prefer to keep the answer just with an explanation of what's going on there. After all, I don't know if it is desired to shorten the curve to 66m, expand it somehow to 77m or have 6 segments with 11m and one last (or first?) with only 4m...

Comment: That makes sense ..:)

Comment: @Christian By the way, if you are wondering why there is a _Length_ mode although it doesn't use a precise value and you would get the same result if you just entered the number of points - it's all about when you use it on many different curve lengths if you prefer the number of points to be always the same or the general length of the segments.